# Swift and parsing JSON into a Dictionary - objectForKey

Tags: json, parsing, swift

I have this Objective C code:

```
NSMutableArray *dataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:0 error:&error];

NSLog(@"Dictionary = %@",dataArray);

NSMutableArray *venues = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSDictionary *venueDic in dataArray) {
    MapPoint *mapPoint = [[MapPoint alloc] init];

    mapPoint.name = [venueDic objectForKey:@"name"];
    mapPoint.image_path = [venueDic objectForKey:@"image_path"];

    [venues addObject:mapPoint];

    NSLog(@"Venue Name: %@", mapPoint.name);

}
```

But I am struggling to translate the FOR loop. I've spent hours already looking for a solution.

Comment: Can you show your translation so far?

Comment: Apart from JSON result working I haven't got very far. Using a NSDictionary instead of NSMutableArray for the NSJSONSerialization makes it crash in Swift too, so I'm stuck

Comment: Figured it out, I was missing the "as String" after the objectForKey("name") as String